# what is the correct way of using `include` to avoid recursive makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am not sure if i understand `include` statement in makefile well enough. I have recently started to use `makefile` for making my analysis  reproducible, and thought i was in the right track until the complexity grew, and seems like `include` statement is the answer as I am also trying to avoid recursive makefile [problem](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) while trying to keep my makefile sane.

To test what include did i ran a dumb test basically created the following.

```
test_folder-|-makefile
            |-test_folder2-|
                           |-test2.mk
```

In the `makefile` i added `include test_folder2/test2.mk`, which according to my understanding would add the code from the test2.mk, so when i run `make`, it will also run `target:dependencies` listed in test2.mk, but it only ran the `target:dependencies` from `makefile`.

It would be great if someone can explain or point me to another blog/stack answer that might explain the right way to avoid recursive makefiles by using `include` statement.

PS: My analysis mostly includes python and R scripts and some command line tools.

**makefile**

```
test.txt:
        echo "test.txt" > test.txt

include test_folder2/test2.mk
```

**test2.mk**

```
test_folder2/test1.txt:
    echo "this is a test" > test1.txt
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without seeing your `makefile` and `test2.mk`, but I will guess: when you ran Make, you did not specify a target, so Make chose the *first* target by default, which was in `makefile`. It had no reason to build any target in `test2.mk`. If you show us the contents of those two files, we can answer more specifically.

Comment: for the above test suite, i just made a dummy makefile...i will add it up in the question. I guess the question is how would i get it to run the test2.mk whilst running `make` from the `test_folder` directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no directory called `test1`, so I will modify the makefiles accordingly.

Second, notice that the `test_folder2/test1.txt` rule builds `test1.txt` *locally*, despite its name. there is more than one way to so what I think you want; one way is to modify `test_folder2/test2.mk`:

```
test_folder2/test1.txt:
    echo "this is a test" > test_folder2/test1.txt
```

In order to execute this rule by running `make` in `test_folder/`, you must modify `makefile`.
To execute only the `test_folder2/test1.txt` rule, do this:

```
test_folder2/test1.txt:

test.txt:
    echo "test.txt" > test.txt

include test_folder2/test2.mk
```

To execute both rules, do this:

```
all: test.txt test_folder2/test1.txt

test.txt:
    echo "test.txt" > test.txt

include test_folder2/test2.mk
```

(Note that "all" is the conventional name for a phony target that comes first in the makefile -- and is therefore the default -- and requires other rules to be executed. You can use another name if you like.)

To execute `test_folder2/test1.txt` dirst, then `test.txt`, do this:

```
test.txt: test_folder2/test1.txt
    echo "test.txt" > test.txt

include test_folder2/test2.mk
```

(It is possible to execute them in the opposite order, but it gets ugly.)

Further refinements are possible, but this is a start.

Comment: I think as far as i understand I missed the whole idea of adding `targets` from `test_folder2/test2.mk` in the main `makefile`. Thanks a lot. I think the #2 solution is best for me right now.